# Help me understand this algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

In above picture , Is Line A and B same ?

I cann't understand how line A simplified to Line B

Please help me understand this

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Yes,  its clear try to simplify

Comment: I cann't understand why -4X is disappeared in line B

Comment: a perfect square trinomial, so factor it

Comment: @SteveJobs Do you have a good handle on factoring?  Notice that $(x-2)^2$ is equal to $x^2-4x+4$.

Comment: This is call: square of difference. Look upon internet: short multiplication formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are the same.

On the LHS it has been simplified:

$y-1+(-8)=y-1-8=y-9$

and on the RHS it has been factorised:

$-2(x^2-4x+4)=-2(x-2)(x-2)=-2(x-2)^2$